# usb wifi linux driver install error

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, usb, installation

```
/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.2013┌──(kuldeep㉿windows)-[~/**Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222**]
└─$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.16.0-kali7-amd64/build M=/home/kuldeep/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.16.0-kali7-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:678: modules] Error 2
```

how to solve this error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please use a different distro. Kali is for advanced users only and is not named after the Hindu god. The error suggests you have not installed and prepped the current kernel source.

Comment: If you can't compile a module Kali is not for you https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/101265